# get a part of a string in an array

Tags: javascript, string, node.js

I am currently using nodejs and I have a function which return a body (String) its like this :

```
 <resourceDescriptors>
<resourceDescriptor name="AllAccounts" wsType="reportUnit" uriString="/reports/samples/AllAccounts" isNew="false">
    <label><![CDATA[Accounts Report]]></label>
    <description><![CDATA[All Accounts Report]]></description>
    <creationDate>1328803684197</creationDate>
    <resourceProperty name="PROP_RESOURCE_TYPE">
        <value><![CDATA[com.jaspersoft.jasperserver.api.metadata.jasperreports.domain.ReportUnit]]></value>
    </resourceProperty>
    <resourceProperty name="PROP_PARENT_FOLDER">
        <value><![CDATA[/reports/samples]]></value>
    </resourceProperty>
    <resourceProperty name="PROP_VERSION">
        <value><![CDATA[0]]></value>
    </resourceProperty>
    <resourceProperty name="PROP_RU_ALWAYS_PROPMT_CONTROLS">
        <value><![CDATA[false]]></value>
    </resourceProperty>
    <resourceProperty name="PROP_RU_CONTROLS_LAYOUT">
        <value><![CDATA[1]]></value>
    </resourceProperty>
</resourceDescriptor>
<resourceDescriptor name="Cascading_multi_select_report" wsType="reportUnit" uriString="/reports/samples/Cascading_multi_select_report" isNew="false">
    <label><![CDATA[Cascading multi select example report]]></label>
    <description><![CDATA[Example report with Cascading multi select input controls]]></description>
    <creationDate>1328803684289</creationDate>
    <resourceProperty name="PROP_RESOURCE_TYPE">
        <value><![CDATA[com.jaspersoft.jasperserver.api.metadata.jasperreports.domain.ReportUnit]]></value>
    </resourceProperty>
    <resourceProperty name="PROP_PARENT_FOLDER">
        <value><![CDATA[/reports/samples]]></value>
    </resourceProperty>
    <resourceProperty name="PROP_VERSION">
        <value><![CDATA[0]]></value>
    </resourceProperty>
    <resourceProperty name="PROP_RU_ALWAYS_PROPMT_CONTROLS">
        <value><![CDATA[true]]></value>
    </resourceProperty>
    <resourceProperty name="PROP_RU_CONTROLS_LAYOUT">
        <value><![CDATA[1]]></value>
    </resourceProperty>
</resourceDescriptor>
                ....
</resourceDescriptors>
```

So I want to get all the **FIRST** name part (without the quotes) from this string and put it in an array or a list (in javascript), like here I would like to have :

```
list[0]=AllAccounts
list[1]=Cascading_multi_select_report
```

I tried several way but it's not working, could you help me ?
Thanks !

Comment: If you use jQuery maybe this will be useful: [jQuery.parseXML()](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.parseXML/)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Using [`xml2js`](https://github.com/Leonidas-from-XIV/node-xml2js):

```
var xml2js = require('xml2js'),
    parser = new xml2js.Parser();

parser.parseString(body, function(err, result) {
  var names = result.resourceDescriptor.map(function(resourceDescriptor) {
    return resourceDescriptor['@'].name;
  });
  console.log(names);
  // => [ 'AllAccounts', 'Cascading_multi_select_report' ]
});
```

**Note:** I'm not that familiar with `xml2js`, there might be better libraries out there, especially if you need to parse large documents.

Answer (score 1):

Here, this will make your life easier.

Learn to use the DOM parser provided in javascript
http://www.w3schools.com/dom/default.asp

Comment: i only did .+ because i do not know what type of "names" are valid.  there could be -, _, digits, and maybe more! :)

Comment: Thanks ! Well I am not using Jquery, can you do me the "forloop" version ? I am really new to javascript  I tried with a for each not working(It's can be letter and digits)

Comment: THanks for the new version , but it say "k is not declared"

Comment: Oops, i copied and pasted, my bad

Comment: Thanks again ,unfortunately it's not working , it's giving me the almost the same full line (twice) like this : `0 => <resourceDescriptor name="AllAccounts" wsType="reportUnit" uriString="/reports/AllAccounts" isNew="false"` and 
`1 => AllAccounts" wsType="reportUnit" uriString="/reports/AllAccounts" isNew="false
`

Comment: With Saebekassebil's regex (\w+) it's giving me : `0 => <resourceDescriptor name="AllAccounts"
1 => AllAccounts` almost there ^^

Comment: the weird thing is also that matches.length = 2 ( I have like 10  <resourceDescriptor name=)

Comment: @ThiefMaster for learning the basics of an item its not bad.  Its a good direction for someone who does not know how to create a for loop.  Everything has its use and purposes, even visual basic... eww

Comment: @Michael: Even for basic it's bad. It teaches you how to write bad JS code, e.g. `setTimeout('a string', ...)`

Comment: I know how to create a for loop, just not sure in javascript :)

Comment: @ThiefMaster there are plenty of sites that teach you bad practices.  If we found everyone who has bad examples we would not have windows or 99% of the programming languages.  (which about 93% are actually bad).

Answer (score 1):

Try using [node-expat](https://github.com/astro/node-expat), a (fast!) streaming XML parsing library.  Assuming your XML document is (or can be) stored as a string:

```javascript
var xp = require('node-expat');

function getResourceDescriptorNames(xmlStr) {
  var names = [], parser = new xp.Parser('UTF-8');
  parser.on('startElement', function(name, attr) {
    if (name === 'resourceDescriptor') names.push(attr.name);
  }).parse(xmlStr);
  return names;
}

getResourceDescriptorNames(myXmlString);
// => ['AllAccounts', 'Cascading_multi_select_report']
```

Note that if your XML document comes from a stream instead of a buffer and you don't wish to buffer it you can simply call `parser.parse(data)` for each chunk of data and it will work fine.

Comment: Yeah thanks i want to try that, i am just searching how to install this module